# Could not find lane 'ios debug'. Available lanes: ios beta

Tags: fastlane

when I added a new fastlane like this in Fastfile:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to pgy"
  before_all do
    ENV["CACHE_GIT_URL"] = ENV["GIT_URL"]
  end

  lane :debug do
    xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode.app"

    match(
        type: "adhoc"
    )

    build_app(
        workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace",
        scheme: "Runner",
        export_method: "ad-hoc",
        skip_archive: true
    )

    pgyer(
        api_key: ENV['PGY_API_KEY'],
        user_key: ENV['PGY_USER_KEY']
    )
  end

  lane :beta do
    xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode_12.4.app"
    if is_ci
      create_keychain(
        name: ENV['MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME'],
        password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"],
        default_keychain: true,
        unlock: true,
        timeout: 3600,
        lock_when_sleeps: false
      )
    end

    match(
      app_identifier: ENV["APP_IDENTIFIER"],
      git_url: ENV["GIT_URL"],
      type: "adhoc",
      readonly: is_ci,
      keychain_name: ENV['MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME'],
      keychain_password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"]
    )

    build_app(
        workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace",
        scheme: "Runner",
        export_method: "ad-hoc",
        skip_archive: true
    )

    pgyer(
        api_key: ENV['PGY_API_KEY'],
        user_key: ENV['PGY_USER_KEY']
    )
  end
end
```

I added a new lane called `debug`, but when I run the command:

```
bundle exec fastlane debug
```

shows error:

```
$ bundle exec fastlane debug                                                                                                                                            ‹ruby-2.7.2›
[✔] 
+-----------------------+---------+--------+
|               Used plugins               |
+-----------------------+---------+--------+
| Plugin                | Version | Action |
+-----------------------+---------+--------+
| fastlane-plugin-pgyer | 0.2.2   | pgyer  |
+-----------------------+---------+--------+

[16:51:14]: ------------------------------
[16:51:14]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[16:51:14]: ------------------------------
+------------------+-----+
|      Lane Context      |
+------------------+-----+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios |
+------------------+-----+
[16:51:14]: Could not find lane 'ios debug'. Available lanes: ios beta

+------+------------------+-------------+
|           fastlane summary            |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action           | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform | 0           |
+------+------------------+-------------+

[16:51:14]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Could not find lane 'ios debug'. Available lanes: ios beta
```

what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Sorry for this question, but I want to ask: Did you save your FastFile before running this command `bundle exec fastlane debug`. And can you try just `fastlane debug` instead of `bundle exec fastlane debug` for the first time.

Comment: Yes, I saved the Fastlane file @Akif

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: this problem disappeared now, but I do not know why this problem happen. Maybe I reinstall ruby or switch and downgrade ruby version avoid this problem. @Akif

Comment: Ok, you can add these possibilities as an answer. This may help others. I've started a bounty that expires in 2 days.

Comment: I think my solution is not a reliable way, maybe someone could explain for detail. I am not sure my way is correct. @Akif

Comment: I've fixed it by comparing the Ruby versions. I end up changing my version from 3.x to 2.7.5 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I will answer to others who have encountered this problem.

Please open the Fastfile file.

edit:

```
lane :... do
  ...
end
```

to your code.